Support in ASP.NET MVC development
I am new into ASP.NET MVC development. I am creating an area with the name of Member and also creating a controller with the name of Dashboard.
In the Dashboard controller, I have two action methods:

Dashboard
MemberList

Now I want to call MemberList from the header part using anchor tag and I tried different methods, but MemberList does not open when I click on MemberList menu.
I tried the below methods to call MemberList view:
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("MemberList","Dashboard")"></a>"

<a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Dashboad" asp-action="MemberList" asp-area="Member"></a>

With both of these methods, MemberList is not opened.
This is the structure of the code:
Controller
Areas -> Member -> Controller -> Dashboard (2 Action Methods: 1. Index, 2. MemberList)

Views
Areas -> Member -> Views -> Dashboard -> 1. Index.cshtml, 2. MemberList.cshtml

I request you provide me the solution for this.
Thank you in advance.

" I tried different methods, but MemberList does not open" Please describe what does happen. Are there any errors?

You need to pass the area as a parameter to Url.Action, as in:
@Url.Action("MemberList","Dashboard", new { Area = "Member" });

But the A tag helper should work too, provided the tag helpers are registered:
<a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="MemberList" asp-area="Member">Member List</a>


Thank you so much my dear friend, It's working. I used your @URL.Action method in achor tag. Thank You

Great, thank you for the feedback! Can you please mark my answer as correct, then?
